# Too many connection created to query virtual object in EF

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I noticed that when I do a simple query of an object in EF that it create lots of connections to the sql DB when I have a virtual property that has a list of child.

for example:

```
public class myobject {

 public virtual List<mychild> childs {get; set;}
}
```

my c# code:

```
var db = new myDBContext();

var result = (from I in db.myobjects
              select I).toList();
```

my html:

```
foreach (var item in Model) {
    @item.childs.property1
}
```

if I look at sql process monitor when the page renders, there are like 25 open connections to render this page.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Without being able to see much of your actual code, I would expect that you are not wrapping your `Context` (db) in a `using` statement.

Comment: When you access the property1 of childs, it has to go back to the database and fetch the child object. By default EF won't pull all the related entities from the database, unless you tell it to. Try db.myobjects.Include("childs") to force the SQL to populate that property

Comment: so based on my c# code above, how do I tell it to grab the childs instead of waiting until the property is accessed?

Comment: He just told you.  `db.myobjects.Include("childs")`

Comment: the multiple connection is only happening on one web server and not on a QA server. I expected that if it happens on one server it should happen on both.

Comment: even if it had to connect back to the DB to get the child data, why make 25 open connections?  I exepect maybe 1-3 open connections.

Comment: Please show us how `db` is instantiated. Also you may be just be seeing connections that are in the connection pool waiting to be re-used. Those connections may not be "live" connections.

Comment: I am the only user on the system and very isolated.  When I am looking at the sql process monitor, I see 1 dbuser for the app.  When I hit f5 to  refresh the page to kick off the page render,  the process monitor shows 20+ db connection. (this only happens in PROD. I have the same code base in QA and QA seems to be working as expected, using 1-3 connections)

Comment: "seems to be working as expected" only means that you haven't triggered the code yet that caused the behavior.

Comment: its like 25 lines of code... a test page.

Comment: I don't think this is an issue with the code or EF.. It looks like it is a database server issue.  I'll repost in a different thread. Thanks for all the info